# Running a shell command from jenkins plugin

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, processbuilder

I want to run a dynamically generated shell command from a jenkins plugin I have written.

I use ProcessBuilder from within my process function to run the shell command. But then I get 'No such file or directory'.

My command is something like: /path/to/directory/ --flag

Am I missing something about running shell commands using ProcessBuilder. Or does it have something to do with the Jenkins workspace. On creating a freestyle project directly from command shell, it does work. It stops working when the freestyle project is created using a plugin.

I will appreciate any help and direction about this.

Comment: Does the command involve an absolute path?

Comment: The path I am using is a absolute path to a nfs mounted location. Will that not work? It works from directly adding it as a 'Execute Shell Command' within Free Style Project.